# Extjs validate in separate files

Tags: validation, extjs

I'm trying to validate fields in my form, but I keep getting an error message.
Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('ExtDoc.views.extfields.FieldsValidator',{
  valEng: function(val) {
    var engTest = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {

      eng: function(val, field) {
        return engTest.test(val);
      },

      engText: 'Write it in English Please',
      // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
      engMask: /[a-zA-Z0-9_\u0600-\u06FF\s]/i
    });
  }

});
```

And I define my field as follow:

```
{
  "name": "tik_moed_chasifa",
  "type": "ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocTextField",
  "label": "moed_hasifa",
  "vtype": "eng",
  "msgTarget": "under"
}
```

The first snippet is in a separate js file, and I have it in my fields js file as required.

When I start typing text in the text field, I keep seeing the following error msg in the explorer debugger:

> "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'eng' "

What could it be? Have I declared something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your own class with a function `valEng(val)`, but you don't instantiate it, neither do you call the function anywhere.
Furthermore, your function `valEng(val)` does not require a parameter, because you are not using that parameter anywhere.

It would be far easier and more readable, would you remove the `Ext.define` part and create the validators right where you need them. For instance if you need them inside an `initComponent` function:

```
initComponent:function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        mobileNumber:function(val, field)  {
            var numeric = /^[0-9]+$/
            if(!Ext.String.startsWith(val,'+')) return false;
            if(!numeric.test(val.substring(1))) return false;
            return true;
        },
        mobileNumberText:'This is not a valid mobile number'
    });
    Ext.apply(me,{
        ....
            items: [{
                xtype:'fieldcontainer',
                items:[{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    vtype: 'mobileNumber',
```

Or, you could add to your Application.js, in the `init` method, if you need it quite often at different levels of your application:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    views: [
    ],

    controllers: [
    ],

    stores: [
    ],

    init:function() {
        Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
            mobileNumber:function(val, field)  {
                var numeric = /^[0-9]+$/
                if(!Ext.String.startsWith(val,'+')) return false;
                if(!numeric.test(val.substring(1))) return false;
                return true;
            },
            mobileNumberText:'This is not a valid mobile number'
        });
    }
```